# Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux

my makefile is

```
 obj - m+= jurgen.o
all:
        [Tab] -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        [Tab] -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 3):

Your spacing looks odd.

Line 1 is

```
obj - m+= jurgen.o
```

I'd expect

```
obj-m += jurgen.o
```

#### Additionally:

You can simplify the rest of the file:

```
.PHONY:%
all: modules

build_dir = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

%:
    $(MAKE) -C $(build_dir) M=$(PWD) $@
```

I'ved reduced duplication, and put the build directory into an overridable variable, so that you can compile for any kernel you have the headers for, not just your currently running one.  I also added `.PHONY` so a file called `all` or `clean` won't prevent Make doing its job.

Answer (score 3):

---

The "standard" module Makefile :

```
obj-m    := jurgen.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

---